# enforcing type signature for toString

Tags: typescript

how do I force the compiler to not overload toString? The closest I have got is to use the never type, but never is still allowed to be implicitly assigned to a var the compiler only complains when something is done with the variable. Who is going to remember to explicitly declare toString calls as strings?

```
type ArrayToStringMethod = {
  (this: { join(a: string): string, length: number }): string
  (this: any): never // if this overload isn't here typescript uses 
                     // Object.toString automatically.
}

type ArrayDontMutate<t> = {
    toString: ArrayToStringMethod
    readonly [index: number]: t
    readonly length: number
} &
Pick<
  Array<t>, 
  'find'   |
  'map'    |
//'join'   | deliberately removed to make toString fail
  'some'   |
  'slice'  |
  'concat' |
  'reduce'>

let a:ArrayDontMutate<string> =['a','b','c'] as any
let b = a.toString() //should fail no join method. b is the never type
```

Answer (score 2):

> how do I force the compiler to not overload toString

There are native interfaces in the `lib.d.ts` type definitions that drive how the type checker works. One of these is the `Object` interface, and this interface has the `toString` method.

If you want to disallow `toString` you can use `--noLib` and create a copy of `lib.d.ts` that doesn't have this method.

## More

- https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html